# jQuery on binding when loading partial

Tags: jquery

I'm loading a partial shown here:

```
<div id="Catering-Dialog" title="Catering for a new booking">
 <div id="itemsTable">
   @{Html.RenderAction("AddCateringItem", new { Model.Booking.BookingID });}
 </div>
</div>
```

and have this jQuery .on()

```
$('a.editRow').on("click", function () {
   alert("clicked");
});
```

Basically, the partial is a table and each row has a cell with "edit" in it and when clicked it should display the alert "Clicked" but nothing at all happens.

Any ideas?

To update:

```
<div id="CateringTable">
<table border="2" bgcolor="#ffffff" id="cateringListTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Time:</th>
        <th>Description:</th>
        <th>Quantity:</th>
        <th>Cost £:</th>
    </tr> 
</thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("_CateringItemEditor", item);
        }
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

This is the code that the renderaction is rendering and each row is a partial that is also rendered, the code for that is as follows:

```
<tr>
            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StartTime)
            <label class="cateringLabel">@Model.StartTime</label></td>

        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Description)
            <label class="cateringLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)</label>
        </td>

        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Quantity)
            <label class="cateringLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Quantity)</label>
        </td>

        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Charge)
            <label class="cateringLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Charge)</label>
        </td> 

        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CateringID)</td>

        <td>
            <a href="#" class="editRow">edit</a>
            <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
        </td>  
</tr>
```

Comment: jquery-1.7.1 are the script files I have

Comment: Can you post complete code of cshtml at http://pastebin.com/. There is no problem with the above code. May be problem is somewhere else. Paste code and share link

Comment: As it turns out, the 'a' tag had a disabled attribute causing it to not do anything when clicked... thanks for the help though haha!

Comment: Great you found the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) fr dynamic elements

```
$("#itemsTable").on("click","a.editRow" function () {
 alert("clicked");
});
```

Event delegation allows you to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector, whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for dynamically loaded elements:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

```
$("#itemsTable").on("click", 'a.editRow',function () {
    alert("clicked");
});
```